# Use Facebook credentials to log my application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to add log in with Facebook button to my application. So i tried to follow this guide.

[Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

I tried to get Android key hash. But i couldn't to run it on my PC cmd.

This is code i tried.

i added my home path to this `%HOMEPATH%`.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

But it shows like this error.

[image]

Can anyone help me to fix this error.

Comment: 1) cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>
2) keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey  -keystore HOMEPATH\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e

Comment: I got the same problem, you need to download openssl, check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUv8NDgu2Xk) it helped me out easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly download openssl from this [a link](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/OpenSSL-Download-25523.html)

Second extract it to Local disk C: name it openssl i.e folder name

third set it in Environment variables. procedure as follows

right click on **My computer->properties->advanced->environment variables
under system variables->click on path and click edit**

Now insert a ';' semi-colon and paste the path of folder openssl. then ok.

now u can see openssl is recognized as command in cmd.

to get KeyHash execute follwing cmd

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "path of ur debug.keystore" | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

Solution for the warning---

```
WARNING: can't open config file: C:/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf
WARNING: can't open config file: C:/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf
openssl:Error: 'base' is an invalid command.
```

1st add below line in environment variable as similar to third step.

set `OPENSSL_CONF=c:\openssl\bin\openssl.cfg`

now run above cmd

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "path of ur debug.keystore" | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

u do get warning but keyHash is returned in cmd...

Comment: Thanks dear. I took KeyHash, But I can not post any post on my Fb account.

Comment: take a look at this [link](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/) it might help you

Comment: dear but it says like this warning. WARNING: can't open config file: C:/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf
WARNING: can't open config file: C:/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf i think my key was incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to print hash key in your log

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        PrintHashKeyInLog();

    }

    public void PrintHashKeyInLog() {

        PackageInfo info;
        try {
            info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "Your package name",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md;
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0)); // String
                something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                Log.e("hash key", something);
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
            Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("exception", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: what you mean by "Your AppId here"