# WARNING: can't open config file: C:/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf

Tags: android, facebook, openssl

I'm developing Facebook application.there i have to obtain hash key.i followed this link--> [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595913/use-facebook-credentials-to-log-my-application) and i did all the things mentioned there to configure OpenSSL now Im having a Error.

i have posted my cmd.'please find below.[image: My Cmd]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get hash key programmatically also. It's easy.
just use this code in your onCreate() method.

```
public void PrintHashKeyInLog() {

        PackageInfo info;
        try {
            info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "Your package name here",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md;
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0)); // String
            //  something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                Log.e("hash key", something);
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
            Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("exception", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

use your package name in

```
info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                        "Your package name here",
                        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
```

just call this method from onCreate() and your hashkey will be printed in logcat.